# Repeat columns in a table

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I am new to PDFsharp and MigraDoc. I have a requirement to generate a dynamic report with a header and a table.

The table should have a number of columns that are fixed and repeated on every page. I understand MigraDoc automatically calculates the width of the table and splits it over multiple pages if required.

Can someone please share an example of the repeated columns on multiple pages? I cant seem to find anything on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current implementation of MigraDoc does not support splitting tables horizontally across pages. Repeated columns that are required for horizontally split tables do not currently work automatically.

Tables automatically split vertically (i.e. across several pages) and header rows are automatically repeated.

To simulate horizontal splitting you can create several tables and merge them.

In our application we chose a workaround: we let the page width grow as needed for the table. This works fine for tables that are to be viewed on the screen, but does not work well for tables that have to be printed.